# What is the decimal form of 1/299,792,458

Tags: definition, rational-numbers

I'm seeking the decimal form to the fraction 1/c, something like 3.35692(548672), where the number in the brackets would be reoccurring integers. Most calculators round after 10 digits, and the calculator app on my Android just computes the numbers endlessly (if I swipe left) making it hard to find the reoccurring pattern.

My intention is to find the decimal form of the definition of the metre.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1}{299792458}$$?

Comment: i think this is not the end

Comment: @DietrichBurde: the OP wants to find the period.

Comment: and have you found the period?

Comment: How accurate is $c$?  If $c$ has been rounded, then the full decimal form might not be useful to you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you even interested in this?

Comment: the value of $c$ is exact, per wikipedia.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The fact is that since 1983 the metre has been re-defied so that the speed of light in $m/s$ is that integer.

Comment: @Hyperplane im interested in this because the answer to 1/c is the time it takes for light to travel 1 metre, which is the definition

Comment: @NickBailuc Yes but as others already pointed out when you deal with physical constants you have to keep in mind that they are not exact, but have some error bar attached to them. So what use is there in computing the period of the decimal representation of $1/c$? It seems really meaningless to me....

Comment: @NickBailuc And even if we take $c$ to be an exact quantity by definition of the meter and second, then this just kinda shifts the goalpost since then you have to deal with the second being defined via the oscillation frequency of some Caesium atom being subject to uncertainty.

Answer (score 10):

The prime factorization of $299792458$ is $2 \cdot 7 \cdot 73 \cdot 293339$.

$10$ has order $6$ mod $7$.

$10$ has order $8$ mod $73$.

$10$ has order $293338 $ mod $293339$.

Therefore, the length of the periodic part is $lcm(6,8,293338)= 3520056 $.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution from *Mathematica* given [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1019853):

```
normalizeDigitSequence = {{{beforeRecurring___, {recurring__}}, 
     c_?NonPositive} :> {{0, beforeRecurring, {recurring}}, 
     c + 1}, {{beforeRecurring___, {recurring__}}, c_?Positive} /; 
     Length[{beforeRecurring}] < c :> {{beforeRecurring, 
      First[{recurring}], RotateLeft[{recurring}]}, c}};
addOverlineToRepeating = {{beforeRecurring___, {recurring___}}, 
     c_?Positive} /; Length[{beforeRecurring}] >= c :> 
   Row[Append[Insert[{beforeRecurring}, ".", c + 1], 
     Overscript[Row[{recurring}], _]]];
RealDigits[1/72] //. normalizeDigitSequence /. addOverlineToRepeating
```

where you'd put in `1/299792458` instead of my example `1/72`.  Alas, with your number, the repeated sequence is (as lhf showed), much too long to print here.